# Unable to extract number & text separately from html

Tags: python, python-3.x

From the html code below I want to get the number separately & the text separately, I am able to get the number but for text it's giving error as shown below. (Note: it is in `for loop`, for few links its working as the `split(b'.')[1]` is matching, if the index is not found its giving error).

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Computers Zone/Google Drive/Python/SANDWICHTRY.py", line 49, in <module>
    sandwich=soup.find('h1',{'class':'headline'}).encode_contents().strip().split(b'.')[1].decode("utf-8")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

HTML code:

```
<h1 class="headline ">1. Old Oak Tap BLT</h1>
```

Ny code:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(pages,'lxml').find('div',{'id':'page'})
rank=soup.find('h1',{'class':'headline'}).encode_contents().strip().split(b'.')[0].decode("utf-8")
print (rank)
sandwich=soup.find('h1',{'class':'headline'}).encode_contents().strip().split(b'.')[1].decode("utf-8")
print(sandwich)
```

Comment: If it splits into just one item (i.e., no `b'.'` in the string), simply don't try and access the second element.

Comment: Use a `regular` expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occures, when there is no `.` in your headline string, i.e. the second element does not exist.

To solve this, get the results, split the string, but do not assume that there are always two elements:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pages = '<h1 class="headline">1. Old Oak Tap BLT</h1>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(pages, 'lxml')
titles = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'headline'}).encode_contents().split(b'.')

for text in titles:  # go through all existing list elements
    print(text.decode("utf-8").strip())
```

Or check for 2 elements in your list prior to reading the elements, e.g.:

```
if len(titles) == 2:
    rank = titles[0].decode("utf-8").strip()
    sandwich = titles[1].decode("utf-8").strip()
```

Comment: I am glad, that this solves your issue. If this is the right answer, you are invited to mark it as accepted.

Comment: sure sir, is there any way to store the number & letter separately in a string? because including regex will make it more complicated.
Thanks alot for your time :)

Comment: There is no regex is my answer included and if you use the second option (`if len(titles) == 2`) you get two strings in `rank` and `sandwich`.

Comment: yeah... but if the len(titles) !=2 then it will skip both the number & letter.
then have to include elif loops?

Comment: Yes, you can use `else` to assign `rank` and `sandwich` with default values.